# How to display custom fields in Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, custom, tab

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="Collect Loan Package" labelWidth="200">
           <apex:PageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">
               <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
//Please help me find a way to display custom fields!!!                   
 *<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.fields.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}"/>*
```

......Didnt copy and paste the whole block.

Answer (score 4):

A single field in this context where you want to pick your own label would be:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.fields.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Lead.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

but as you are picking the standard label that will be output with just this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Lead.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}"/>
```

So the syntax is the SObject reference name (`Lead` in this case) dot the API name of the custom field (assuming `Interim_Financials_Statements__c` in this case) wrapped in the Visualforce expression delimiters `{! }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these to know the difference yourself.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}" />

<apex:outputField value="{!Lead.Interim_Financials_Statements__c}" />
```

More Visualforce components can be found here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm